# JQuery UI datepicker rendering issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have an issue with JQuery UI datepicker in Chrome.

It fills all free "slots" with disabled yesterday date like image below.

[image: Jquery UI datepicker issue]

There are no errors in Console when initialize the datepicker and in Firefox and Edge work correctly. The issue is only in Chrome.

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    numberOfMonths: 2
});
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Share how you initialized please